# Protractor no waiting for web page to change

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor

Using Angular 5 with Protractor.

Having trouble waiting for the browser url to change to see if the user logs in and then lands on the internal dashboard page.

**Spec:**

```
fdescribe('Suite 1', function() {
  it('should login and land on the dashboard page', function() {
    // Arrange
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    const baseUrl = 'confidentialUrl';
    const email = 'email';
    const password = 'password';

    // Act
    browser.get(baseUrl);
    element(by.id('username')).sendKeys(email);
    element(by.id('password')).sendKeys(password);
    element(by.css('.submit-btn')).click();

    // Assert
    browser.wait(5000);
    const currentUrl = browser.getCurrentUrl();
    expect(currentUrl).toEqual('confidentialUrl/dashboard');
  });
```

**Error I get when I do a "protractor conf.js":**

> Failed: Wait condition must be a promise-like object, function, or a
>   Condition object

Comment: Because you turn off synchronization, you will need to resolve your own promises.

Answer (score 1):

[`browser.wait`](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) requires an object as a first parameter which is condition object or promise-like object. For example you can create an [expected condition](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions) from `protractor`

```
// Expected condition object
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// wait 5 seconds for expected condition
// in this case it will wait for url contains a given value
browser.wait(EC.urlContains('foo'), 5000).then(() => {
   // then you can assert here
   const currentUrl = browser.getCurrentUrl();
   return expect(currentUrl).toEqual('confidentialUrl/dashboard');
});
```

We resolved this kind of problems with using [ExpectedConditions](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions).

I edited your code, so in your case:

```
fdescribe('Suite 1', function() {
  it('should login and land on the dashboard page', function() {
    // Arrange
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    const baseUrl = 'confidentialUrl';
    const email = 'email';
    const password = 'password';

    // Act
    browser.get(baseUrl);
    element(by.id('username')).sendKeys(email);
    element(by.id('password')).sendKeys(password);
    element(by.css('.submit-btn')).click();

    // Assert
    const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.urlContains('confidentialUrl/dashboard'), 5000).then(() => {
      const currentUrl = browser.getCurrentUrl();
      return expect(currentUrl).toEqual('confidentialUrl/dashboard');
    })

  });
```

or you can:

```
fdescribe('Suite 1', function() {
      it('should login and land on the dashboard page', function() {
        // Arrange
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

        const baseUrl = 'confidentialUrl';
        const email = 'email';
        const password = 'password';

        // Act
        browser.get(baseUrl);
        element(by.id('username')).sendKeys(email);
        element(by.id('password')).sendKeys(password);
        element(by.css('.submit-btn')).click();

        // Assert
        return browser.driver.wait(function() {
          return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
            return expect(url).toEqual('confidentialUrl/dashboard');
          });
        }, 10000);

      });
```

Comment: Could you edit my code above in the question and then il try it. Bit confused from the above example.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I ran the test and got this error:     Failed: Wait timed out after 5004ms

Comment: Can you try to adding more seconds?

Comment: Yeah I added 10 seconds and got the same error. I did notice that the url doesnt change e.g. from /login to /dashboard page. Seems like it pauses the browser rather than waits for it to change

Comment: The last one didnt work either. It just pauses for 10 seconds on the login

Comment: Are you sure that your app is redirecting after login to page `confidentialUrl/dashboard` ?

Comment: Yeah I tried the steps manually first. It fills email and password and then clicks the button. Then the url doesnt change.